# Function returns unexpected value

Tags: r, function

I would like to get a function that returns a matrix.

```
mat1 <- function(k)
{
  mat2 <- matrix( 0, ncol = 664, nrow = 182 )
  for (i in 1:664)
  {
    mat2[,i] <- weight0.0025(i,k)
  }
}
```

where weight0.0025 is a function that returns a 182 long vector, but somehow this doesn't work.

What is even more frustrating is that

```
mat2 <- matrix( 0, ncol = 664, nrow = 182 )
for(i in 1:664)
{
  mat2[,i] <- weight0.0025(i,k)
}
```

works as expected.

I know I could write in the form of a 3 dimensional array but I need to optimize on k.

Comment: "weight0.0025" a function name ?

Comment: Yes it is a function that returns a vector of length 182

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function needs a return statement.

```
mat1 <- function(k){
  mat2 <- matrix(0, ncol = 664, nrow = 182)
  for (i in 1:664){
    mat2[,i] <- weight0.0025(i,k)
  }
  return(mat2)
}
```

Comment: So it was that simple... Thank you.